# How to input complex values to the OpenCV function cv.dft()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, dft

I am trying to implement what is stated in a research paper. It describes how to extract Fourier features from images. I tried to follow the steps while coding but repeatedly faced errors related to datatypes and dimensions of the input array.
So I ask that how to input complex values to the function

I have followed the following instructions from the research paper

Fourier Descriptors: Fourier descriptors provide a way to encode
an image boundary by mapping every pixel position ( x , y ) into a
complex number ( x + i y ).

1. Record the coordinate values of each pixel sequentially
   (moving clockwise along the shape)
2. Construct a complex-valued vector using coordinate values
   recorded in step 1 i.e., ( x , y ) → ( x + i y ) .
3. Take DFT of the complex-valued vector

My problem comes at step 3

This is my implementation

```py
def get_dft(image):
    coordinates = cv.findNonZero(image)
    # the code below removes an unnecessary dimension
    coordinates = coordinates.reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 2)
    y = coordinates[:, 1] * 1j  # convert to complex numbers
    # the code below removes an unnecessary dimension
    y = y.reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 1)
    x = coordinates[:, 0].reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 1)
    # the statement below will convert from two separate arrays
    # to a single array with each element  
    # of the form [a + jb]
    t = x + y
    # below is where the error occurs
    dft = cv.dft(t, flags=cv.DFT_COMPLEX_INPUT)
```

This is the error I get

```
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
```

when I convert as

```py
a = numpy.ndarray(t)
```

I get

```
ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

It wants to say there are greater than 32 dimensions. I don't understand why that happens

and When I try as

```py
a = numpy.ndarray([t])
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

In short I want to follow the steps as mentioned in the paper, make a complex valued vector like

```
[[a+jb],[c+jd]...]
```

and pass it to the DFT function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem as

```py
def get_dft(image):
    coordinates = cv.findNonZero(image)
    coordinates = coordinates.reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 2).astype(float)
    y = coordinates[:, 1].reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 1)
    x = coordinates[:, 0].reshape(coordinates.shape[0], 1)
    t = cv.merge([x, y])  # used to convert to 2 channel
    dft = cv.dft(t, flags=cv.DFT_COMPLEX_INPUT)
```

I tried all that numpy api and all that seemed to fail for reasons I don't understand, but fortunately the OpenCV one

```py
cv.merge(...)
```

worked.

It takes multiple input arrays and joins to make a multi channel output.

Also I tried inputting complex numbers to the OpenCV API function

```py
cv.dft(...)
```

it wasn't the correct way of inputting complex numbers.
[OpenCV documentation explains complex input here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ggaf4dde112b483b38175621befedda1f1ca07b45079b38d60e7837dfb666a55299b)

It states that the flag, cv.DFT_COMPLEX_INPUT

> specifies that input is complex input. If this flag is set, the input must have 2 channels. On the other hand, for backwards compatibility reason, if input has 2 channels, input is already considered complex

Note the the problem I also faced was converting to two channel, happened due to the fact the I had not properly understood the the structure cv::UMat(), that is required as input to the function.

The summary is,
If you want to input complex numbers into the OpenCV API function

```py
cv.dft(...)
```

your input must consist of 2 channels, to accomplish making a two channel array, the OpenCV function,

```py
cv.merge(...)
```

[link to its documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4), seems to get the job done right when you are trying to combine multiple individual channels.